# Accept Input from user through datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I Have a **DataGridView** with **datagridviewcomboboxcolumn**, I'd Like the user to choose an item from datagridviewcomboboxcolumn and have the choice to write it himself ,the input field should also be the Combobox if this item does not exist in this Dropdown, the written choice will be only inserted in the database not added as another choice in the dropdown.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to achieve. Should the written choice never be visible or should it be visible when you restart your program? Where exactly do you want the input for the new item?

Comment: the input should be combobox

Comment: The ComboBox should work as a DropDown and a Text field

Answer (score 0):

To make a column in datagridview of combobox type you can use following code:

1. Add column in datagridview

   ```
   using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

   string sqlConnection = "Data Source";
   SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(sqlConnection);
   //Get bind from database.
   string qryGetCategory = "Query to get data for combo box";
   SqlCeCommand cmdCat = new SqlCeCommand(qryGetCategory, conn);
   SqlCeDataAdapter daCat = new SqlCeDataAdapter(qryGetCategory, conn);
   DataTable dtCat = new DataTable();
   daCat.Fill(dtCat);

   //Combobox column.
   DataGridViewComboBoxColumn ComboBoxCol = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
   ComboBoxCol.DataSource = dtCat;
   ComboBoxCol.Name = "Column name";
   ComboBoxCol.ValueMember = "Value of member";
   ComboBoxCol.DisplayMember = "Member to be show";
   ComboBoxCol.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
   datagridview.Columns.Add(ComboBoxCol);
   ```

Comment: @M.Aj if you find answer useful please mark it as answer so it will help other's too.